# Fastest way to check if a string is JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I need a really, really fast method of checking if a string is JSON or not. I feel like this is not the best way:

```
function isJson($string) {
    return ((is_string($string) &&
            (is_object(json_decode($string)) ||
            is_array(json_decode($string))))) ? true : false;
}
```

Any performance enthusiasts out there want to improve this method?

Comment: Consider only using `json_decode` once... also, check the input and return values of `json_decode`.

Comment: So, which one is the answer?

Comment: The ternary switch here is redundant. Your statement already evaluates as a boolean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine whether a string is valid JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187576/how-to-determine-whether-a-string-is-valid-json)

Comment: Accept the answer of  Lewis Donovan ...it is working fine

Comment: looking at the solutions, **performance vs simplicity** should have been the prime focus of OP because fastest always depends on the use case, for eg., If you know you'll always deal with object/array, checking for first char of the string should suffice. Generalizing a solution can be never be "fastest"; "faster", may be.

Comment: @Kirk-Ouimet lots of great answers here.  Can you accept one to give credit where credit is due?

Comment: Update 2021: Most solution here focus on the **shortest** way, but the OP asked for the **fastest** way. This is the fastest solution I found - compared to all other approaches in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45241792/313501

Comment: json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

Answer (score 780):

```
function isJson($string) {
   json_decode($string);
   return json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE;
}
```

PHP >= 8.3 solution:

use [json_validate()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-validate.php) built-in function

Comment: Looks like everyone is loving this answer. Any explanation why?

Comment: I believe PHP 5.3 > is needed to use the json_last_error function

Comment: I think it's good because it doesn't rely on heuristics, uses native php functionality, and is about as future-proof as you're gonna get; it just tells you straight up whether there were any errors in decoding the string.  No errors => valid JSON.

Comment: Checking first character of string for `{`, `[` or first symbol of any other literal can potentially greatly speed this one up when many of incoming strings are expected to be non-JSON.

Comment: The problem with this is empty `$string` values, which will return true even though they are considered invalid JSON.

Comment: $phone = '021234567';
var_dump(isJson($phone));

return true
no! it should return false.

Comment: Beware, this function will return true for any number also, whether you specify it as a string or a true number. `6.5 = true, '300' = true, 9 = true` etc. So this might be a valid JSON value but the function might not behave as you expect, if you want to check only for valid JSON strings with `{}` or `[]`;

Comment: I agree with Oleg, upful vee and BadHorsie, and accepted answer should be mario's answer, because this function does not tell you is it a JSON or not, it tells you just is json_decode probe has errors or not. So this function name should be isJsonDecodeProbe();

Comment: Sorry. I'm down-voting this because of reasons mentioned above. Depends on what exactly you require from the function, but if any kind of user-input validity is being done, there is potentially a small loophole.

Comment: Really best solution. Should be accepted. |
http://i.imgur.com/fYYgTKF.png |
**Result 01** = _first code_ |
**Result 02** = _this  answer_ |
**x** = _times repeated_ |
**y** = _sec. execution_

Comment: Surely it just needs
`if (is_numeric($string)) return false;`
as the first line of the function to catch number only $string values?

Comment: terrible answer. For input strings consisting solely of digits, the validation will pass. Surely, a string of digits is not a valid JSON.

Comment: @M1K1O - What are you referencing with 'Result 01' and 'Result 02?'  It's not entirely clear what is the best answer...

Comment: It's worth noting that this works correctly in theory. Unfortunately PHP's `json_decode` function has a number of bugs, which will allow invalid JSON to be parsed in odd ways. `isJson('0123')` should return `false` because `0123` is not JSON, however `isJson('123')` should return `true` because `123` *is* JSON. It seems that some people are not aware that [JSON allows values to be more than just an object or array](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf). Valid JSON values may be objects, arrays, numbers, strings, booleans, and `null`.

Comment: We obviously use json_decode() if we are really going to parse the data and use it in our code. I such case there is no hamper of speed as you are doing a obvious thing. If there is no need to decode. for example if you are just storing it in DB then you may consider alternative way.

Comment: I believe this answer highlights that in most cases, testing for json-ness is probably unnecessary or even detrimental - just decode everything and handle the errors.  If you're conditionally encoding your data based on whether it's scalar or not, you should probably just *encode* everything because json's handling of scalar data is pretty straight forward as it is. If other data types are more common, you should be attempting to deal with those first before you even get to attempting a json decode.

Comment: This function is incorrect because, if you send only string value to the function it returns true. It has to validate as is it object as answered by user1653711 below.

Comment: It will return true if you pass "12345" as a string.

Comment: Sorry. I'm down-voting because string number is passed the check.

Comment: A non-zero number will pass this test, so I'm downvoting. You need to `json_decode()` the string and check if it's an object or an array. If it fails this test, then it's not valid JSON. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51636727/7546845

Comment: You might want to catch any `ErrorExceptions` or check if it's not an array or object. I combined this with [Tinh Dang's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49729033/3209381)

Comment: Just to clear things out. A plain number (int or float), bools, null and strings (with quotes at start and end) are valid json values! This function does exactly, what it should do. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: it returns true if you supply numbers or letters

Comment: how fast will this function work with big jsons?

Comment: This works better function isJson($string) {
  @json_decode($string);
   return is_string($string) && json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE;
}

Comment: Using PHP 5.6.40 (not true for 7.1.13 and over. Maybe only < 7), if there is an error, a call to `json_encode` will fail. To fix it, right after calling `json_decode($REAL_DATA)` call `json_decode("{}")`.

Comment: php 8.3 will implement new function called json_validate() to validate if an string contains a valid json.

Comment: It works great until the JSON string is "0" (the number zero). It returns that "JSON" is valid...

Answer (score 235):

> **Answer to the Question**

The function `json_last_error` returns the last error occurred during the JSON encoding and decoding. So the fastest way to check the valid JSON is

```
// decode the JSON data
// set second parameter boolean TRUE for associative array output.
$result = json_decode($json);

if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    // JSON is valid
}

// OR this is equivalent

if (json_last_error() === 0) {
    // JSON is valid
}
```

Note that `json_last_error` is supported in PHP >= 5.3.0 only.

> **Full program to check the exact ERROR**

It is always good to know the exact error during the development time. Here is full program to check the exact error based on PHP docs.

```
function json_validate($string)
{
    // decode the JSON data
    $result = json_decode($string);

    // switch and check possible JSON errors
    switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            $error = ''; // JSON is valid // No error has occurred
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            $error = 'The maximum stack depth has been exceeded.';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            $error = 'Invalid or malformed JSON.';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            $error = 'Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded.';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            $error = 'Syntax error, malformed JSON.';
            break;
        // PHP >= 5.3.3
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            $error = 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded.';
            break;
        // PHP >= 5.5.0
        case JSON_ERROR_RECURSION:
            $error = 'One or more recursive references in the value to be encoded.';
            break;
        // PHP >= 5.5.0
        case JSON_ERROR_INF_OR_NAN:
            $error = 'One or more NAN or INF values in the value to be encoded.';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_TYPE:
            $error = 'A value of a type that cannot be encoded was given.';
            break;
        default:
            $error = 'Unknown JSON error occured.';
            break;
    }

    if ($error !== '') {
        // throw the Exception or exit // or whatever :)
        exit($error);
    }

    // everything is OK
    return $result;
}
```

> **Testing with Valid JSON INPUT**

```
$json = '[{"user_id":13,"username":"stack"},{"user_id":14,"username":"over"}]';
$output = json_validate($json);
print_r($output);
```

> **Valid OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 13
            [username] => stack
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 14
            [username] => over
        )
)
```

> **Testing with invalid JSON**

```
$json = '{background-color:yellow;color:#000;padding:10px;width:650px;}';
$output = json_validate($json);
print_r($output);
```

> **Invalid OUTPUT**

```
Syntax error, malformed JSON.
```

> **Extra note for (PHP >= 5.2 && PHP < 5.3.0)**

Since `json_last_error` is not supported in PHP 5.2, you can check if the encoding or decoding returns boolean `FALSE`. Here is an example

```
// decode the JSON data
$result = json_decode($json);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    // JSON is invalid
}
```

Comment: Little precision :  if this json is valid but a previous decoded one is invalid, your code is going to work correctly, because : "*Returns the last error (if any) occurred during the __last__ JSON encoding/decoding.*"

Comment: Thanks @Madan, the "json_decode" verification solved to me that I running PHP 7.0.

Comment: Surely json_decode could just return false for the literal false, so a check `((strlen($json) === 5) && ($json !== 'false'))` should also be undertaken to avoid that edge?

Comment: @Bruno If the last decoding works without errors then `json_last_error` returns `JSON_ERROR_NONE`.

Answer (score 106):

All you really need to do is this...

```php
if (is_object(json_decode($MyJSONArray))) 
{ 
    ... do something ...
}
```

This request does not require a separate function even. Just wrap is_object around json_decode and move on. Seems this solution has people putting way too much thought into it.

Comment: @RomanM.Kos Just to be clear, if the array is a simple array, then you need to use `is_array` in addition to `is_object`, else `is_object` will return false for simple arrays encoded as JSON. So @ggutenberg is right in this case. Passing the true argument to `json_decode` forces an object to be returned as an array. You could in theory always force the decode to an array and just check of `is_array`, that should work.

Comment: @userabuser If i `json_encode($array)` for simple PHP array, and then do `json_decode($str)` i will receive object, but not array. `json_decode($str, true)` forces to convert into array. Why do complicated string in your code?
Check for `is_array(json_decode($str, true))` and some time later when you read it you will understand that decoded must be only an array. Much harder to guess `is_object(json_decode($MyJSONArray))` "Oh, here i am checking for decoded is an array or not?"

Comment: @RomanM.Kos No, that's not correct, http://codepad.viper-7.com/OFrtsq - as I said, you can always force `json_decode` to return an array to save you checking for object and array, but if you don't AND you `json_decode` what was a simple array to begin with, you will receive an array in return on decode, not an object. You must use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` if you want to always force an object on encode IF passing a simple array.

Comment: Downvote for saying: `This request does not require a separate function even`. Strictly speaking, no solution requires a separate function. The point of a function is _not_ to make multiple lines of code look like one line of code.  The point of the function is to make the JSON-checking process standard everywhere in your application, so that different programmers (or the same programmer over time) don't use different checking procedures at different stages in the flow of the program.

Answer (score 77):

Using [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) to "probe" it might not actually be the fastest way. If it's a deeply nested structure, then instantiating a lot of objects of arrays to just throw them away is a waste of memory and time.

So it might be faster to use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) and the **[RFC4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) regex** to also *ensure validity*:

```
  // in JS:
  var my_JSON_object = !(/[^,:{}\[\]0-9.\-+Eaeflnr-u \n\r\t]/.test(
         text.replace(/"(\\.|[^"\\])*"/g, '')));
```

The same in PHP:

```
  return !preg_match('/[^,:{}\\[\\]0-9.\\-+Eaeflnr-u \\n\\r\\t]/',
       preg_replace('/"(\\.|[^"\\\\])*"/', '', $json_string));
```

Not enough of a performance enthusiast to bother with benchmarks here however.

Comment: great idea, my understanding is that this only checks for validity (all strings enclosed in strings) and not the correct syntax.

Comment: It's actually more a check for invalidity and against JS exploits. Verifying the structure would require a more elaborate `(?R)` regex, doable, but seemingly nobody attempted that yet.

Comment: This is, indeed, the best way to try before going though an ugly brute force sequence of failures to determine what it actually is. This also (partly) answered [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115222/determine-data-type-from-file-get-contents)

Comment: Complete recursive regex to verify JSON here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json/3845829#3845829 - But it turns out PHPs `json_decode` is always faster than a PCRE regex. (Though it's not very optimized, no synthetic tests found, and might behave differently in Perl..)

Comment: This answer is only partly correct. The regex does not check for valid json-strings but rather a string safely being passed into javascript using `eval()`

Comment: @vee Yes, thanks for the note. But let's keep it here [incorrectly], so nobody actually uses that in production.

Comment: @mario After removing the `g`, I get a `Warning: preg_replace():
Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at...` message in PHP.  Seems that you may need to swap `[^"\\]` to `[^\\"]`

Comment: @cartbeforehorse Okay, thanks. I fixed the escaping wholesome for PHPs double quoted string context then.

Comment: @mario Sorry for being dumb. But why does *everything* need to be double-escaped?

Comment: @cartbeforehorse It doesn't. Mostly decoration. It's just the literal backslash which does indeed require doubly escaping. For `\r` `\n` `\t` it only makes sense so PHP doesn't interpolate them, but let PCRE interpret them (only was required for `/x` mode). The other occurences do not strictly need it; yet still "the backslash escapes itself" in all string PHP contexts. So one could consider it more exact.

Comment: @mario Okay, I see. So basically, the PHP escapes the backslashes before the reg-exp engine gets to see it. As far as the reg-exp engine is concerned, there are half the number of backslashes in the string as what we humans see.  _"Like reg-exp wasn't complicated enough already"_

Comment: By some reason the first regexp `/"(\\.|[^"\\\\])*"/` doesnt work for utf8 special characters like `\u00e1` **i just change the regexp to** `/"(\\.|[^"])*"/u` and seems to work allright on php 5.5 on windows.

Comment: I was curious to see if this was actually faster than using json_decode to see if a string is valid JSON so I ran some benchmarks. I ran 100,000 passes of a two-dimensional array that had been encoded using json_encode.

`PHP version : 5.5.34
Platform : Darwin
--------------------------------------
test_json_decode          : 5.608 sec.
test_regex                : 10.428 sec.`

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ee4f2bfa6556ce2343bd4cde0f6fd344c6008931
Regex is definitely the faster method

Comment: @Asheliahut not completely true, the regex is really slow when checking against large non-JSON payloads. `json_decode()` is pretty fast compared to regex when doing check against JSON payloads. However `json_decode()` is super fast against non-JSON compared to the regex method. So I'd say before choosing any of those methods ask yourself the question what type of payload you are most often expecting to check against.

Comment: Could be great to add some benchmark even though you're enthousiast at it. You don't need to do it. @AlexPlumb already did it for you.

Answer (score 72):

This will return *true* if your string represents a **json array or object**:

```
function isJson($str) {
    $json = json_decode($str);
    return $json && $str != $json;
}
```

It rejects json strings that only contains a number, string or boolean, although those strings are technically valid json.

```
var_dump(isJson('{"a":5}')); // bool(true)
var_dump(isJson('[1,2,3]')); // bool(true)
var_dump(isJson('1')); // bool(false)
var_dump(isJson('1.5')); // bool(false)
var_dump(isJson('true')); // bool(false)
var_dump(isJson('false')); // bool(false)
var_dump(isJson('null')); // bool(false)
var_dump(isJson('hello')); // bool(false)
var_dump(isJson('')); // bool(false)
```

It is the shortest way I can come up with.

Comment: Rather than var_dump, you could put this in a PHPUnit test-case. Otherwise I'm both surprised and happy to learn it's true.

Comment: Why does everyone else have such long winded answers when this works great? Thanks.

Comment: Simply, lovely! Didn't check for "fastest way" or performance wise but this one sure covers all the cases I'd ever check for. This is a classic example for the infamous proverb **"Don't use sledgehammer to crack a nut"**. From a programmer point of view, it is always better to keep the code simple, short and easy to understand, performance vs simplicity is another debate out of scope for this thread.

Comment: This is a neat bit of logic, but also note that it returns false for empty arrays. For example: `var_dump(isJson('[]')); // bool(false)`. According to the documentation on booleans, this is because PHP evaluates arrays with zero elements as false. Here is a minor amendment to adjust the return statement; it performs an identical comparison on the decoded output which handles this case: `return $json !== false && $str != $json;`

Comment: @j13k Identical comparison evaluates `isJson('hello')` to true, which isn’t valid json. Loose comparison is chosen on purpose here. I don’t have a quick solution for the empty array/object situation, except an ugly `return $json == '[]' || ...`

Comment: @Cyril, apologies—I missed that case because my test function includes additional checks to short-circuit the function before calling `json_decode`. Because the 'hello' string triggers a JSON error, the output of the function is `NULL`, so an additional `!is_null` check is enough to yield the correct results with your test data: `return $json !== false && !is_null($json) && $str != $json;`

Comment: This is the answer that everyone need, should be the accepted answer instead.

Answer (score 34):

We first perform some type checks and string comparisons before attempting to decode the JSON string. This gives us the best performance because `json_decode()` can be slow.

```php
/**
 * Returns true, when the given parameter is a valid JSON string.
 */
function is_json( $value ) {
    // Numeric strings are always valid JSON.
    if ( is_numeric( $value ) ) { return true; }

    // A non-string value can never be a JSON string.
    if ( ! is_string( $value ) ) { return false; }

    // Any non-numeric JSON string must be longer than 2 characters.
    if ( strlen( $value ) < 2 ) { return false; }

    // "null" is valid JSON string.
    if ( 'null' === $value ) { return true; }

    // "true" and "false" are valid JSON strings.
    if ( 'true' === $value ) { return true; }
    if ( 'false' === $value ) { return true; }

    // Any other JSON string has to be wrapped in {}, [] or "".
    if ( '{' != $value[0] && '[' != $value[0] && '"' != $value[0] ) { return false; }

    // Verify that the trailing character matches the first character.
    $last_char = $value[strlen($value) -1];
    if ( '{' == $value[0] && '}' != $last_char ) { return false; }
    if ( '[' == $value[0] && ']' != $last_char ) { return false; }
    if ( '"' == $value[0] && '"' != $last_char ) { return false; }

    // See if the string contents are valid JSON.
    return null !== json_decode( $value );
}
```

---

Extra: Use this logic to safely double-decode JSON

This function uses the same logic but either **returns the decoded JSON object** or the **original value**.

I use this function in a parser that recursively decodes a complex object. Some attributes might be decoded already by an earlier iteration. That function recognizes this and does not attempt to double decode the value again.

```php
/**
 * Tests, if the given $value parameter is a JSON string.
 * When it is a valid JSON value, the decoded value is returned.
 * When the value is no JSON value (i.e. it was decoded already), then 
 * the original value is returned.
 */
function get_data( $value, $as_object = false ) {
    if ( is_numeric( $value ) ) { return 0 + $value; }
    if ( ! is_string( $value ) ) { return $value; }
    if ( strlen( $value ) < 2 ) { return $value; }
    if ( 'null' === $value ) { return null; }
    if ( 'true' === $value ) { return true; }
    if ( 'false' === $value ) { return false; }
    if ( '{' != $value[0] && '[' != $value[0] && '"' != $value[0] ) { return $value; }

    $json_data = json_decode( $value, $as_object );
    if ( is_null( $json_data ) ) { return $value; }
    return $json_data;
}
```

Note: When passing a **non-string** to any of the other solution in this SO question, you will get [dramatically degraded performance](https://gist.github.com/stracker-phil/6a80e6faedea8dab090b4bf6668ee461#gistcomment-4015077) + wrong return values (or even fatal errors). This code is bulletproof and highly performant.

Comment: I'm not sure, why this answer is downvoted and even has a delete request.
My performance test clearly shows that it's the fastest method by far. Here is the performance comparison script: https://gist.github.com/stracker-phil/6a80e6faedea8dab090b4bf6668ee461

Comment: +1 for sheer effort :) I think it is amazing that your test is actually faster when it actually has 8 "if" statements.  I assume people won't like it because it is not at all elegant and it really is not much of an overhead difference unless you needed to check about a million bits of text.

Comment: @EnigmaPlus thanks :) And right, the code is no elegant one-liner, but the question was about finding the **fastest** way, not the most elegant/shortest. `json_decode` is shorter, but requires PHP to initialize an internal JSON-Parser instance that is quite complex and *a lot slower* than 8 simple `if`s 

Comment: Your example of $json_data = json_decode($value,null,1); returns NULL when evaluating like '{"a":5}' or '[1,2,3]'. Should be two levels, like: json_decode($value,null,2);

Comment: This is definitely the FASTEST and most FLEXIBLE solution!!

Comment: is_numeric($value) should be the first evaluation.

Comment: @EricP Thanks for your feedback! I've updated the answer and also improved the gist with my test-cases to cover all this.

Comment: The time wasted on this useless code is the only "degraded performance" here. "the root of all evil" never sounded more true.

Comment: Can you add the `is_array( json_decode( , true) )` speed ? I use array decoding it in my code and won't execute it twice if is_array is fast.

Answer (score 29):

**PHP 8.3**

Native PHP function

```
json_validate(string $json, int $depth = 512, int $flags = 0): bool
```

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/json_validate

**PHP < 8.3**

A method that provides similar results to `json_validate()` above

```
function is_json($string) {
  return is_numeric($string)
    || in_array($string, ['null', 'true', 'false']
    || ( is_bool($string) && $string )
    || (
      !empty($string) 
      && is_string($string) 
      && is_array(json_decode($string, true)) 
      && json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE
    );
}
```

Sometimes it can be helpful to see if the JSON object **has** data, either an object or array

```
function has_json_data($string) {
  return !empty($string) 
    && is_string($string) 
    && is_array($array = json_decode($string, true)) 
    && !empty($array) 
    && json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE;
}
```

Comment: +1 for actually thinking about the problem in a real-world context.

Comment: `if(is_string($string) && is_array(json_decode($string, true)) && (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE)){   // json is valid  }else{ // not valid }`

Comment: see this blog post https://subinsb.com/php-check-if-string-is-json/

Comment: As of June 2023, json_validate() is officially part of PHP 8.3 Alpha-2 release.

Comment: @upful bare numbers are valid JSON, as are the values `true`, `false`, and `null`. And you should never use fixed values in place of constants.

Answer (score 29):

The simplest and fastest way that I use is following;

```
$json_array = json_decode( $raw_json , true );

if( $json_array == NULL )   //check if it was invalid json string
    die ('Invalid');  // Invalid JSON error

 // you can execute some else condition over here in case of valid JSON
```

It is because  [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) returns NULL if the entered string is not json or invalid json.

### Simple function to validate JSON

If you have to validate your JSON in multiple places, you can always use the following function.

```
function is_valid_json( $raw_json ){
    return ( json_decode( $raw_json , true ) == NULL ) ? false : true ; // Yes! thats it.
}
```

In the above function, you will get true in return if it is a valid JSON.

Comment: `json_decode('null') == NULL` and `null` is a valid JSON value.

Comment: I have tested if 'null' is valid json at [json.parser.online](http://json.parser.online.fr/) but it seems that its not valid json. And [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is php core function to validate json so I doubt to get some false result in our output.

Comment: Rather than trust some unverified website, [consider consulting the spec, which disagrees (pg 2)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf). Alternatively, try `JSON.parse('null')` in  your dev console.

Comment: The related question of [Is null valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39124954/14032355).

Answer (score 24):

```
function is_json($str){ 
    return json_decode($str) != null;
}
```

http://tr.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php return value is null when invalid encoding detected.

Comment: I think this sould be: `json_decode($str)!=null;` or otherwise the function should be called `is_not_json`.

Comment: That function would be better renamed "is something other than JSON"!

Comment: @user166390, [`json_decode('null')` is valid JSON according to the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf), and should return the value of `null`.

Comment: Please also note that with this method `is_json('false')` and `is_json('[]')` will return `false` as type is not checked. I think this method should rather return `$str === null || json_decode($str) !== null`.

Comment: The related question of [Is null valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39124954/14032355).

Answer (score 16):

I found this question after coming across something similar in my work, yesterday. My solution in the end was a hybrid of some of the approaches above:

```
function is_JSON($string) {

  return (is_null(json_decode($string))) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

Comment: I wasn't used too as well, hehe. Since PhpStorm and Magento Code Sniffer tool I was using always complained with me, I started adopting this approach. In the end we get cleaner code and get used to it. :P

Comment: The related question of [Is null valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39124954/14032355).

Comment: Thanks for this heads up, @ikhvjs. If you wanted to anticipate this case, you could prepend the contents of the function above with the condition: `if (is_null($string)) return TRUE;`

Comment: is_null already returns bool, can be shortened to `return is_null(json_decode($string));`

Comment: possibly more consistent with the name of the function, one would expect `true` to be returned for a valid JSON formatted `$string`... so: `return !is_null(json_decode($string));`

Comment: Thanks for this, @berend. At one point the code read: `return (is_null(json_decode($string))) ? FALSE : TRUE;`. Later, I changed it to: `return is_null(json_decode($string));`. I don't know what I was thinking. I've changed it back. Thanks again.

Answer (score 14):

This will do it:

```php
function isJson($string) {
    $decoded = json_decode($string); // decode our JSON string
    if ( !is_object($decoded) && !is_array($decoded) ) {
        /*
        If our string doesn't produce an object or array
        it's invalid, so we should return false
        */
        return false;
    }
    /*
    If the following line resolves to true, then there was
    no error and our JSON is valid, so we return true.
    Otherwise it isn't, so we return false.
    */
    return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
}

if ( isJson($someJsonString) ) {
    echo "valid JSON";
} else {
    echo "not valid JSON";
}
```

As shown in other answers, [`json_last_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) returns any error from our last json_decode(). However there are some edge use cases where this function alone is not comprehensive enough. For example, if you [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) an integer (eg: `123`), or a string of numbers with no spaces or other characters (eg: `"123"`), the `json_last_error()` function will not catch an error.

To combat this, I've added an extra step that ensures the result of our `json_decode()` is either an object or an array. If it's not, then we return `false`.

To see this in action, check these two examples:

- [Only check with `json_last_error()`](https://3v4l.org/UCpb0)
- [Checking for object/array first](https://3v4l.org/hhHqs)

Comment: `"hello"` is a valid JSON, and it's not an object neither an array, `json_last_error()` is enough

Comment: `json_last_error()` returns error code `4` when you `json_decode()` the string `"hello"`. Example here: https://3v4l.org/lSsEo

Comment: Your code is wrong, `hello` is not a valid JSON, but `"hello"` is

https://3v4l.org/OEJrQ

Comment: Same for `false`, `46783`, `null`, etc. All valid json.

Answer (score 14):

Using PHPBench with the following class, the below results were achieved:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

/**
 * @Revs(1000)
 * @Iterations(100)
 */
class BenchmarkJson
{
    public function benchCatchValid(): bool
    {
        $validJson = '{"validJson":true}';
        try {
            json_decode($validJson, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
            return true;
        } catch(\JsonException $exception) {}
        return false;
    }

    public function benchCatchInvalid(): bool
    {
        $invalidJson = '{"invalidJson"';
        try {
            json_decode($invalidJson, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
            return true;
        } catch(\JsonException $exception) {}
        return false;
    }

    public function benchLastErrorValid(): bool
    {
        $validJson = '{"validJson":true}';
        json_decode($validJson, true);
        return (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE);
    }

    public function benchLastErrorInvalid(): bool
    {
        $invalidJson = '{"invalidJson"';
        json_decode($invalidJson, true);
        return (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE);
    }

    public function benchNullValid(): bool
    {
        $validJson = '{"validJson":true}';
        return (json_decode($validJson, true) !== null);
    }

    public function benchNullInvalid(): bool
    {
        $invalidJson = '{"invalidJson"';
        return (json_decode($invalidJson, true) !== null);
    }
}
```

```
6 subjects, 600 iterations, 6,000 revs, 0 rejects, 0 failures, 0 warnings
(best [mean mode] worst) = 0.714 [1.203 1.175] 1.073 (μs)
⅀T: 721.504μs μSD/r 0.089μs μRSD/r: 7.270%
suite: 1343ab9a3590de6065bc0bc6eeb344c9f6eba642, date: 2020-01-21, stime: 12:50:14
+---------------+-----------------------+-----+------+-----+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------+-------+
| benchmark     | subject               | set | revs | its | mem_peak   | best    | mean    | mode    | worst   | stdev   | rstdev | diff  |
+---------------+-----------------------+-----+------+-----+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------+-------+
| BenchmarkJson | benchCatchValid       | 0   | 1000 | 100 | 2,980,168b | 0.954μs | 1.032μs | 1.016μs | 1.428μs | 0.062μs | 6.04%  | 1.33x |
| BenchmarkJson | benchCatchInvalid     | 0   | 1000 | 100 | 2,980,184b | 2.033μs | 2.228μs | 2.166μs | 3.001μs | 0.168μs | 7.55%  | 2.88x |
| BenchmarkJson | benchLastErrorValid   | 0   | 1000 | 100 | 2,980,184b | 1.076μs | 1.195μs | 1.169μs | 1.616μs | 0.083μs | 6.97%  | 1.54x |
| BenchmarkJson | benchLastErrorInvalid | 0   | 1000 | 100 | 2,980,184b | 0.785μs | 0.861μs | 0.863μs | 1.132μs | 0.056μs | 6.54%  | 1.11x |
| BenchmarkJson | benchNullValid        | 0   | 1000 | 100 | 2,980,168b | 0.985μs | 1.124μs | 1.077μs | 1.731μs | 0.114μs | 10.15% | 1.45x |
| BenchmarkJson | benchNullInvalid      | 0   | 1000 | 100 | 2,980,184b | 0.714μs | 0.775μs | 0.759μs | 1.073μs | 0.049μs | 6.36%  | 1.00x |
+---------------+-----------------------+-----+------+-----+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------+-------+
```

Conclusion: The fastest way to check if json is valid is to return `json_decode($json, true) !== null)`.

Comment: very nice :) i admire you

Answer (score 9):

Easy method is to check the json result..

```
$result = @json_decode($json,true);
    if (is_array($result)) {
        echo 'JSON is valid';
    }else{
        echo 'JSON is not valid';
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

While PHP 8.3 which is still in development, will come with new memory-efficient `json_validate()` function, you can use it with older PHP versions (7.1 and newer) thanks to amazing [Symfony Polyfill](https://github.com/symfony/polyfill) component.

Simply add following package to your project:

```bash
composer require symfony/polyfill-php83
```

and use it in your application:

```php
if (json_validate($data)) {
  // do sometihng
}
```

Thanks to this approach, you can use new PHP features in older applications and migrate to PHP 8.3 without any code changes in the future as your code will automatically use the built-in function when it's available.

Answer (score 6):

in [GuzzleHttp](http://docs.guzzlephp.org):

```
/**
 * Wrapper for json_decode that throws when an error occurs.
 *
 * @param string $json    JSON data to parse
 * @param bool $assoc     When true, returned objects will be converted
 *                        into associative arrays.
 * @param int    $depth   User specified recursion depth.
 * @param int    $options Bitmask of JSON decode options.
 *
 * @return mixed
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException if the JSON cannot be decoded.
 * @link http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
 */
function json_decode($json, $assoc = false, $depth = 512, $options = 0)
{
    $data = \json_decode($json, $assoc, $depth, $options);
    if (JSON_ERROR_NONE !== json_last_error()) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
            'json_decode error: ' . json_last_error_msg());
    }

    return $data;
}

/**
 * Wrapper for JSON encoding that throws when an error occurs.
 *
 * @param mixed $value   The value being encoded
 * @param int    $options JSON encode option bitmask
 * @param int    $depth   Set the maximum depth. Must be greater than zero.
 *
 * @return string
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException if the JSON cannot be encoded.
 * @link http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
 */
function json_encode($value, $options = 0, $depth = 512)
{
    $json = \json_encode($value, $options, $depth);
    if (JSON_ERROR_NONE !== json_last_error()) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
            'json_encode error: ' . json_last_error_msg());
    }

    return $json;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
//Tested thoroughly, Should do the job:
public static function is_json(string $json):bool
{
    json_decode($json);
    if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The RFC for the **json_validate()** function is implemented and will be part of PHP 8.3

This method will be the fastest and most efficient way to achieve what the question is asking for.

[github - implementation code](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/9399)

[rfc - of json_validate()](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/json_validate)

Comment: Maybe you want to [edit] this question now that 8.3 has been released and there's documentation for the function.

Answer (score 5):

Earlier i was just checking for a null value, which was wrong actually.

```
    $data = "ahad";
    $r_data = json_decode($data);
    if($r_data){//json_decode will return null, which is the behavior we expect
        //success
    }
```

The above piece of code works fine with strings. However as soon as i provide number, it breaks up.for example.

```
    $data = "1213145";
    $r_data = json_decode($data);

    if($r_data){//json_decode will return 1213145, which is the behavior we don't expect
        //success
    }
```

To fix it what i did was very simple.

```
    $data = "ahad";
    $r_data = json_decode($data);

    if(($r_data != $data) && $r_data)
        print "Json success";
    else
        print "Json error";
```

Comment: Nice solution. Handles the typing issue very well!

Answer (score 5):

We need to check if passed string is not numeric because in this case json_decode raises no error.

```
function isJson($str) {
    $result = false;
    if (!preg_match("/^\d+$/", trim($str))) {
        json_decode($str);
        $result = (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another simple way

```
function is_json($str)
{
    return is_array(json_decode($str,true));
}
```

Comment: This isn't correct. Any PHP type can be encoded into JSON such as objects, strings, etc and the json_decode function is expected to return them.
This is only true if you are always decoding arrays and no other variable types.

Comment: @Chaoix using `json_decode($str,true)` makes it convert objects to arrays so it will pass the is_array check. You correct about strings, integers, etc. though.

Comment: I see the what you mean about the second parameter on json_encode. I still think @Ahad Ali's solution is a much better one in terms of typing and only doing a json_decode once in your algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried some of those solution but nothing was working for me. I try this simple thing :

```
$isJson = json_decode($myJSON);

if ($isJson instanceof \stdClass || is_array($isJson)) {
   echo("it's JSON confirmed");
} else {
   echo("nope");
}
```

I think it's a fine solutiuon since JSON decode without the second parameter give an object.

EDIT : If you know what will be the input, you can adapt this code to your needs. In my case I know I have a Json wich begin by "{", so i don't need to check if it's an array.

Comment: Your JSON could potentially just be an array, in which case it would be an array rather than instead of stdClass

$foo = "[1, 1, 2, 3]";
var_dump(json_decode($foo)); =>

array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(1)
  [2]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  int(3)
}

Answer (score 2):

**Should be something like this:**

```
 function isJson($string)
 {
    // 1. Speed up the checking & prevent exception throw when non string is passed
    if (is_numeric($string) ||
        !is_string($string) ||
        !$string) {
        return false;
    }

    $cleaned_str = trim($string);
    if (!$cleaned_str || !in_array($cleaned_str[0], ['{', '['])) {
        return false;
    }

    // 2. Actual checking
    $str = json_decode($string);
    return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE) && $str && $str != $string;
}
```

**UnitTest**

```
public function testIsJson()
{
    $non_json_values = [
        "12",
        0,
        1,
        12,
        -1,
        '',
        null,
        0.1,
        '.',
        "''",
        true,
        false,
        [],
        '""',
        '[]',
        '   {',
        '   [',
    ];

   $json_values = [
        '{}',
        '{"foo": "bar"}',
        '[{}]',
        '  {}',
        ' {}  '
    ];

   foreach ($non_json_values as $non_json_value) {
        $is_json = isJson($non_json_value);
        $this->assertFalse($is_json);
    }

    foreach ($json_values as $json_value) {
        $is_json = isJson($json_value);
        $this->assertTrue($is_json);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like that you're checking if it's a string. Goes well in combination with the first solution to avoid `ErrorException` if the string is array or object.

Comment: I am glad you can write code to speed up internal ph funcs. I think my computer was crashing trying json_decode a number. this 200 lines of code is definitely less assembly code. Can you write code in 0s and 1s? I am just joking with you my friend. My argument in the form of a joke is do you really think and benchmarked all this much code to be faster than Php internally written in C a lower level program? This function has all sorts of breakpoints you are literally wasting more human time worrying about CPU time that you are mathematically speaking only increasing if it makes any difference.

Comment: I went and found the source code for you: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/json/json.c

Comment: The function itself is only 18 lines of codes. Even including the unittest it's only around 60 lines. I'm sure you are a joker.
2nd it's written purely in PHP to solve the issues we have here, it's also easy to understand and implement. I'm sure it's only takes time in miliseconds each time calling the function. 
3rd unless you can give some better solution in PHP, please do, otherwise it's so inappropriate to mention C here, or you just showing off your C skill sir?

Comment: It's so weird to see someone comparing a solution gave 5 years ago, with a function very recently added in PHP 8.3 (few months ago) written in C implemented directly in core of PHP, then talk about nonsense topic. Anyway please go and add a new answer, and don't forget to mention that from 8.3 we can use json_validate and use some form of joke you have there to bring joy to the world.

Comment: A number of your `$non_json_values` are perfectly valid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Hi here's a little snippet from my library, in this first condition I'm just checking if the data is json then return it if correctly decoded, please note the substr usage for performance ( I haven't seen yet any json file not begining neither by { or [

```
$input=trim($input);
if ((substr($input, 0, 1) == '{' && substr($input, -1) == '}') or (substr($input, 0, 1) == '[' && substr($input, -1) == ']')) {
    $output = json_decode($input, 1);
    if (in_array(gettype($output),['object','array'])) {
        #then it's definitely JSON
    }
}
```

Comment: There have been 34 answers posted to this question, many of which also subscribe to the (mistaken) belief that JSON has to represent an array or an object. Is this answer doing anything different from the other 3 dozen answers?

Comment: I beleive this answer has many benefits, for most use cases we already know we're expecting a json string, so this is checking for the curly brackets so if they're not found, there won't be the need to json_decode. +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about performance or elegance of my solution, but it's what I'm using:

```
if (preg_match('/^[\[\{]\"/', $string)) {
    $aJson = json_decode($string, true);
    if (!is_null($aJson)) {
       ... do stuff here ...
    }
}
```

Since all my JSON encoded strings start with {" it suffices to test for this with a RegEx. I'm not at all fluent with RegEx, so there might be a better way to do this. Also: [strpos()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) might be quicker.

Just trying to give in my tuppence worth.

P.S. Just updated the RegEx string to `/^[\[\{]\"/` to also find JSON array strings. So it now looks for either [" or {" at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
function isJson($string) {
    $obj = json_decode($string);
    return json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE && gettype($obj ) == "object";
}
```

this works and doesn't return true for numbers

**new update**

The above solution does not have good performance if the JSON is long and you don't need to use $obj

if you just want check, it's better to use below function

```
function isJson($string) {
    if(is_numeric($string)) return false;
    json_decode($string);
    return json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE;
}
```

Comment: IMHO the best solution if you also want to actually use the decoded object, should it be json

Comment: you're right. I updated the answer

Comment: A number is valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Update: json_validate() Will Be live in PHP 8.3

FYI:

I am working on an RFC to add a new function in php that is able to validate-only a json-string without generating and object/array in the process.

Why a validation-only function? because json_decode() creates an array/object while parsing the json-string, affecting the amount of memory being use; this means that max memory limit can be reach while validating a json-string.

To give you an idea, check this code [performance_test_json_validate()_vs_json_decode()](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/9399/files#diff-3a3990633d4ae2bdc00a0ea24e32abd4ec070ac7dc64c69ad81367f46a0d37dc):

In that test we can see that the new function **json_validate()** uses 0 MB to validate the json-string, while **json_decode()** needed 109 MB to do it (because it creates an in memory array/object while parsing.

This is Work In Progress at the moment, but I am posting this as I am interested in your opinion about it (not if you think is worth to have it or not, I mean , from technical point of view).

Github: https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/9399

RFC (Work in progress): https://wiki.php.net/rfc/json_validate

Looking forward for your opinion/support on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6041773/563247) How about the following:

```
<?php

    $json = '[{"user_id":13,"username":"stack"},{"user_id":14,"username":"over"}]';
    //$json = '12';

    function isJson($string) {
        json_decode($string);
        if(json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            if(substr($string,0,1) == '[' && substr($string,-1) == ']') { return TRUE; }
            else if(substr($string,0,1) == '{' && substr($string,-1) == '}') { return TRUE; }
            else { return FALSE; }
        }
    }

    echo isJson($json);
?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the substring check be made before executing the decode to save time if the error is found in that check? I would imagine that 4 substring checks would be faster than a json_decode, but if someone could back me up with this assumption I'd appreciate any thoughts on this.

Comment: That's a fare argument. I don't know the processing time involved, but if it's faster then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion from me :)

```php
function isJson(string $string) {
  return ($result = json_decode($string, true)) ? $result : $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I recommend

```
if (!in_array(substr($string, 0, 1), ['{', '[']) || !in_array(substr($string, -1), ['}', ']'])) {
  return false;
} else {
  json_decode($string);
  return (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE);
}
```

Comment: The following are valid JSON strings and will not pass your checks: `2352`, `"foo"`, `null`

Answer (score -2):

Freshly-made function for PHP 5.2 compatibility, if you need the decoded data on success:

```
function try_json_decode( $json, & $success = null ){
  // non-strings may cause warnings
  if( !is_string( $json )){
    $success = false;
    return $json;
  }

  $data = json_decode( $json );

  // output arg
  $success =

    // non-null data: success!
    $data !==  null  ||

    // null data from 'null' json: success!
    $json === 'null' ||

    // null data from '  null  ' json padded with whitespaces: success!
    preg_match('/^\s*null\s*$/', $json );

  // return decoded or original data
  return $success ? $data : $json;
}
```

Usage:

```
$json_or_not = ...;

$data = try_json_decode( $json_or_not, $success );

if( $success )
     process_data( $data );
else what_the_hell_is_it( $data );
```

Some tests:

```
var_dump( try_json_decode( array(), $success ), $success );
// ret = array(0){}, $success == bool(false)

var_dump( try_json_decode( 123, $success ), $success );
// ret = int(123), $success == bool(false)

var_dump( try_json_decode('      ', $success ), $success );
// ret = string(6) "      ", $success == bool(false)

var_dump( try_json_decode( null, $success ), $success );
// ret = NULL, $success == bool(false)

var_dump( try_json_decode('null', $success ), $success );
// ret = NULL, $success == bool(true)

var_dump( try_json_decode('  null  ', $success ), $success );
// ret = NULL, $success == bool(true)

var_dump( try_json_decode('  true  ', $success ), $success );
// ret = bool(true), $success == bool(true)

var_dump( try_json_decode('  "hello"  ', $success ), $success );
// ret = string(5) "hello", $success == bool(true)

var_dump( try_json_decode('  {"a":123}  ', $success ), $success );
// ret = object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["a"]=> int(123) }, $success == bool(true)
```