# Is null valid JSON (4 bytes, nothing else)

Tags: json

Hot debate today:

Is the text stream `null` valid JSON?

According to http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627:

> ...
>   2.  JSON Grammar
>
> A JSON text is a sequence of tokens.  The set of tokens includes
>   six    structural characters, strings, numbers, and three literal
>   names.
>
> A JSON text is a serialized object or array.

Should this interpreted as both statements must be true in order for the text to be valid JSON?

- http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/issues/detail?id=49 seems to indicate (at the bottom) that this is invalid.
- http://json.parser.online.fr/ also flags this as invalid.

However, many other libraries seem to permit it, and indeed, it seems like a single valid token *could* be a legitimate result.

Is there a definitive answer?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Note! This answer is no longer correct, see answer by @niksnut.]

Yes, both statements must be true. The literal token `null` is a JSON *value*. A JSON text is a serialized object or array, which requires {} or [].

Comment: How does it come then that most JSON parsers out there accept `null' as valid document? A typical examples are Node.JS (JSON.parse('null')  => null or echo 'null' | python -mjson.tool => null.

Comment: echo '7' | python -mjson.tool yields 7, so I infer that tool apparently is willing to parse isolated JSON literal values as well as complete (object or array) JSON texts.

Comment: Ruby’s JSON parser rejects just `null` as a value by default: `ruby -r json -e 'JSON.parse("null")'` givens “unexpected token at 'null' (JSON::ParserError)”

Comment: Some parsers also choke on `"[]"`.

Comment: Note! This answer is no longer correct, see @niksnut answer below

Comment: @moderators: (if any listening) Should we as community edit this answer with warning that it's outdated?

Answer (score 96):

[RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) and its successor [RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259) drop the limitation that a JSON text must be an object or an array. The grammar specifies:

> JSON-text = ws value ws

where

> value = false / null / true / object / array / number / string

Thus, "null" is now a valid JSON document.