# Why does the httpclient in angular 4.3 return Object instead of any?

Tags: angular, typescript

The new HttpClient class in Angular 4.3 seems to return **Object** instead of **any** by default.

Is there a particular reason for doing that, given the typescript documentation says:

> *Don’t ever use the types Number, String, Boolean, or Object. These
> types refer to non-primitive boxed objects that are almost never used
> appropriately in JavaScript code.*
>
> https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html

I'm aware that I can provide my own return type using:
`this.httpService.get<any>('/api1').subscribe(Data => {console.log(Data.Value1)});`

It would seem to be easier to just make it the default. I'm aware that I can create a type specific for the data it's returning, but using any seems like it'd make it more flexible.

I was going to extend the HttpClient and override the methods to return any, but before I do that I wanted to see if there was something I was missing.

Comment: Am I missing something? The doc says nothing about Object https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient

Comment: I guess the answer is in your question : 

> These types refer to non-primitive boxed objects that are almost never
used appropriately in JavaScript code. > The rest seems a little rhetorical to me.

Comment: @HarryNinh, you're right the documentation seems to imply it returns an any. But when I actually use it, the json results get mapped to an Object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyword in *non-primitive boxed objects that are almost never used appropriately in JavaScript code* is ***almost***.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39124954/3731501), JSON document can be anything but `undefined` and symbol, this makes `Object` more suitable type than `any`.

The behaviour of `any` versus `Object` is explained in [the manual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any):

> The any type is a powerful way to work with existing JavaScript, allowing you to gradually opt-in and opt-out of type-checking during compilation. You might expect Object to play a similar role, as it does in other languages. But variables of type Object only allow you to assign any value to them - you can’t call arbitrary methods on them, even ones that actually exist

`any` response type allows to call arbitrary methods on it, which is not a desirable behaviour, including the ones that don't exist.

A suitable type for JSON response is

```
any[] | object | boolean | number | string | null
```

And a precise one (like is shown [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3496#issuecomment-128553540), with the addition of `null`) is:

```
type JSONValue = boolean | number | string | null | JSONObject | JSONArray;

interface JSONObject {
    [x: string]: JSONValue;
}

interface JSONArray extends Array<JSONValue> { }
```

This is likely the way it should be done in HttpClient. While `Object` is less accurate yet still more applicable type than `any`.

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer:** There are a lot of overloads available with all sorts of return types - so I may be reading more into this than I should.

I havent seen anything specific to back this up, but my guess is that its because `Object` more accurately describes the type since its stricter than `any` and "natively" associates with generic javascript object methods (see https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/02/24/typescript-2-2-the-object-type). In my humble estimation at least, this seems to fit the change to return the response body (as assumed JSON) by default.

*See this question for a **way** more in depth comparison of Object vs any: [TypeScript any vs Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961203/typescript-any-vs-object)*

There is also a great article on HttpClient by Alligator.io here: https://alligator.io/angular/httpclient-intro/

TLDR:

> ...One major difference is that a JSON response is expected by default, so there’s no need to explicitly parse the JSON response anymore.
>
> [Text in between removed for brevity]
>
> By default the HttpClient returns the body of the response.
>
> [More text removed]
>
> If you expect something else than JSON as the response, you can specify the expected response type using an object with the responseType key...

I'd really recommend reading the whole article.