# Angular 4 HttpClient with HATEOAS REST server

Tags: angular, hateoas

My Angular 4 application consume Spring Data REST API HATEOAS server, I am using HttpClient and I see that it returns Object instead of `any` like http.
I read this question: [Why does the httpclient in angular 4.3 return Object instead of any?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45133992/why-does-the-httpclient-in-angular-4-3-return-object-instead-of-any)
and I got it. I have complex json with many fields like this:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "customers": [
      {
        "sid": "c44fdb6f-9b7c-4f75-8d4c-7542f54037b7",
        "createdDate": "2017-08-01T13:06:23Z",
        "lastModifiedDate": "2017-08-01T13:06:23Z",
        "lastModifiedBy": "admin",
        "name": "Customer 1",
        "username": "customer1",
        "address": "Via xxxxx",
        "city": "Adria",
        "landlinePhone": "+39042000000",
        "mobilePhone": null,
        "email": "email@test.it",
        "fax": null,
        "vatNumber": "IT01000020295",
        "taxCode": null,
        "iban": null,
        "swift": null,
        "enableEcommerce": true,
        "balance": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "new": false,
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "....:8080/api/v1/customers/1"
          },
          "customer": {
            "href": "....:8080/api/v1/customers/1"
          },
          "movements": {
            "href": "....:8080/api/v1/customers/1/movements"
          },
          "country": {
            "href": "....:8080/api/v1/customers/1/country"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "....:8080/api/v1/customers{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "....:8080/api/v1/profile/customers"
    },
    "search": {
      "href": "....:8080/api/v1/customers/search"
    }
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 20,
    "totalElements": 1,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "number": 0
  }
}
```

HttpClient does not permit to do `response.page.totalElements` because, like I said, the response type is a Object and not of type `any`.
I am wondering which is the best way to accomplish my goal; I have 2 ideas in mind:

- Cast the response to `any`. In this case I would be able to access to fields without any typecheck of course.
- Create several objects to map the HATEOAS response: probably I would need at least 2-3 interfaces and than 1 class for each model entity.
  This approach seems quite complex, maybe overkill compared to the first solution and I always need a cast from object to my specific entity model;this means I could have a runtime exception due a wrong typecast.

Could you give me some advice and best practice to reach my goal and follow the idea angular's team drew?

Comment: Have you tried response['page'].totalElements?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem and I found one possible solution:

```
// Java: Spring Data REST Repository
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "result", path = "customers")
public interface CustomerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Customer, Long> {
}

// TypeScript model
export interface ListResult<T> {
   _embedded: EmbeddedList<T>;
  _links: any;
  page: any;
}

export interface EmbeddedList<T> {
  results: T[];
}

export class Customer{
  name: String;
  ... bla bla ...
}

// AJAX Call
http.get('/api/customers').subscribe(response => {
  const customers: Customer[] = response._embedded.results;
});
```

All repositories must have **collectionResourceRel="results"**.