# How can I encode null using a JObject in json.net?

Tags: json.net

In newtonsoft json.net when we use

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(null, Formatting.Indented)
```

I get `"null"` in the output as expected.
Now, I would like to represent objects (which can be null) with a JObject, but it throws an exception when I try to encode null this way:

```
(JObject.FromObject(null)).ToString(Formatting.Indented)
```

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: The only thing `JObject.FromObject` could return in this case would be `null`, and instead it throws an exception. If you actually were to get back a `JObject`, you would have an empty JSON object, which is different. So `JObject.FromObject(null)` should be translated to just `null`, and you can't call `ToString` on that. Basically, you're in a sort of edge case here.

Comment: Since the various J* types are classes, the special case of `null` is not handled by an instance of any of those types, but instead just a reference of `null`.

Comment: In essence, there is no way to represent `null` objects with a `JObject`, because the smallest `JObject` instance you could possibly have is an empty object, which is not the same as `null`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Let me ask something else, I believe `"null"` is valid json, correct? It seems to be according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/39124954/750124 So, how is that json/string represented in json.net?

Comment: See Brians answer below. You don't do it with `JObject`.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the JValue but I wanted a JObject. But it's ok, in the end I realized that I had to use JObject or null, instead of representing the null in the JObject. It makes me change a dll that I didn't want to, but I'll survive. Thanks so much for everyone's help. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To represent a null value with a [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm), you can use [`JValue.CreateNull()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue_CreateNull.htm).

```
JToken token = JValue.CreateNull();
string json = token.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you are just trying to cast an object that may or may not be null to a JToken, you can use the implicit value conversion operators by just casting it to JToken.

```
JObject obj = new JObject();
string s = null;
int? i = null;
obj.Add("s", (JToken)s);
obj.Add("i", (JToken)i);
var serialized = obj.ToString(Formatting.Indented);
```