# Snowflake : Object_construct leaving null values when i used copy command to frame json file as out put

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I use copy command of snowflake which is below  returns a file with content json

```
 copy into @elasticsearch/product/sf_index 
 from (select object_construct('id',id, alpha,'alpha')from table limit 1)  
 file_format = (type = json, COMPRESSION=NONE), overwrite=TRUE, single = TRUE, max_file_size=5368709120;
```

data is
id alpha
1 null

the output file is

```
{
   "id" :1
}
```

but I need to have the null values

```
{
   "id" :  1,
   "alpha" : null
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need the null values in your JSON?  That defeats the purpose of JSON, which is to send only the data that is needed.

Comment: do you expect a string null ?  in your file ?

Comment: @MikeWalton I'm indexing the records in es, for the developer, they should have null  values for handling es search result. that's the reason.
Thanks

Comment: When querying JSON data, you will get a NULL returned for any JSON attribute that isn't present in the data.  So, there shouldn't be a need to include the attribute with a NULL.

Comment: @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon no. Actual null not "null" or 'null' .

Comment: @MikeWalton when queried , es is not returning all attributes which doesn't have any values(with null ), any special query is needed.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the function `OBJECT_CONSTRUCT_KEEP_NULL`.

Documentation: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_construct_keep_null.html

Example:

```
select OBJECT_CONSTRUCT_KEEP_NULL('id',id, alpha,'alpha')
```

Answer (score 0):

Will it be possible for you to check programmatically if the value is null and it is null use the below

```
select object_construct('id',1,'alpha',parse_json('null'));
```

Per SnowFlake documentation

*If the key or value is NULL (i.e. SQL NULL), the key-value pair will be omitted from the resulting object. A key-value pair consisting of a not-null string as key and a JSON NULL as value (i.e. PARSE_JSON(‘NULL’)) will not be omitted.*

The other option is, just send it without the null attribute in Elastic and then take care of the retrieval from Elastic.

Comment: First thanks for your reply.

select object_construct('id',1,'alpha', ifnull(alpha ,parse_json('null'))  from sometable);

returns {}
Parse JSon does'nt work inside ifnull.

Comment: "take care of the retrieval from Elastic."
_search on index returns not null fields attributes only. is there any way to return not indexed attribute with null?

Answer (score -1):

How about this

```
select object_construct('id',id, 'alpha', case when alpha is not null  then alpha  else 'null' end )from table limit 1;
```

case should be supported by the copy command.

"null" is a valid in json document as per this SO

[Is null valid JSON (4 bytes, nothing else)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526995/is-null-valid-json-4-bytes-nothing-else)

Ok another possible way is this using union

```
select object_construct('id',id, 'alpha', parse_json('NULL') )from table  where  alpha is null
union 
select object_construct('id',id, 'alpha', alpha )from table  where  alpha is not null;
```

Comment: it contains String null  enclosed with "" .

Comment: even tried 
select object_construct('id',id, 'alpha', case when alpha is not null  then alpha  else  PARSE_JSON('null') end )from table limit 1;
but it is not working.

Comment: Yes I know that. This the issue with this object_construct function seems like.

Comment: what are you going to do with this json file ? Are you going to load it again ? whats the issue if the keys with 'null' is not present ?

Comment: @Sundar please take a look at the answer I have modified it.

Comment: that makes my query formation to  complex  one.
I have handled it in program level. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
select object_construct('id', id,'alpha', IFNULL(alpha, PARSE_JSON('null'))) from table limit 1
```

Use IFNULL to check if the value is null and replace with JSON 'null'