# JSON.NET when ToObject can return null

Tags: c#, json.net

This is the method signature of `ToObject<T>()`. Notice that it returns nullable `T`. I am wondering given what JObject value the `ToObject` will return null.

```
public T? ToObject<T>()
{
    return (T?)ToObject(typeof(T));
}

JObject x = ???;
x.ToObject<???>() == null // when this can happend?
```

Comment: There is only handful possible values in [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) - did you tried all 7?

Comment: It can return null when the root JSON token is `null`, which is a well-formed JSON document in [rfc8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-2).  See [Is null valid JSON (4 bytes, nothing else)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39124954).  LINQ to JSON represents a `null` JSON token with a non-null `JValue` returned by [`JValueCreateNull()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue_CreateNull.htm) with `JValue.Type = JTokenType.Null`.

Comment: See also [Strange behavior in json.net: why is a null JToken replaced with a non-null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51777115/3744182) for confirmation that Json.NET represents a null token with a special non-null `JValue`.  Do those two questions answer yours also?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce it.

Comment: By the way, there is no method [`ToObject()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Methods_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) declared for `JObject`.  The `ToObject()` methods are [declared for `JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject.htm) and inherited without being overridden by `JObject`.  It is true that `JToken.ToObject()` will never return null when token is actually a `JObject` because a `null` token will be represented by a `JValue` not a `JObject`.

Comment: For a demo of `JToken.Parse("null").ToObject<T>()` returning null for various types `T`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/JBkwaz.

Comment: On further thought, it's also possible a custom `JsonConverter` could return null for some non-null JSON object value, so my previous statement that *`JToken.ToObject()` will never return null when token is actually a `JObject`* is not actually guaranteed to be true when the converter in question is applied to the type `T` or registered with the [global default settings](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DefaultSettings.htm).