# PHP Fails with loose string comparison?

Tags: php, json, string-comparison

This is my first post, I hope I'm doing everything OK asking my question:
I want to create a function which detects whether a string is valid JSON or not. I already read good topic here ([Fastest way to check if a string is JSON in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041741/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-string-is-json-in-php)) but I wanted to add the check functionality for the first character as this function will get lot of non-JSON input. Yet it keeps failing, I don't know why...

Here's the function I wrote so far:

```
function isJson($string){
    $string = trim($string);
    vardump($string);  //for debugging
    if($string[0]!='{'||$string[0]!='['){ //check for first char
      echo("{$string[0]}!={ OR {$string[0]}!=["); //this actually prints {!={ OR {!=[ every time it comes across valid JSON...
      return false;
    }
    if(json_decode($string)==true)return true;
    else return false;
    }
```

Could you help me with this please, as it is starting to drive me insane?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: what does you vardump look like? ( and it should be var_dump($string))

Comment: Not sure if you gain any speed by checking the first character yourself. I guess the "json_decode" is clever enough to stop parsing as soon as it detects that a json string is not correctly formatted. Wild guess , but you should benchmark it.

Comment: @Jim: My vardump looks like this: string(65) "[{"os":"iOS","hardware":"iPad"},{"os":"iOS","hardware":"iPhone"}]"
vardump is my function which only wraps var_dump() in <pre> tags.

Comment: @FrédéricClausset: Thanks, once this gets sorted out I'll benchmark it and post the results here!

Comment: woah we missed the obvious !  of course this is always true  if($string[0]!='{'||$string[0]!='[') ,  you need an &&

Comment: Indeed, I also realized it after reading mpratt's answer, so I'll choose that one as correct. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Here are the benchmark results:
**String being tested against:** 3203 chars long valid JSON, but removed '{' from the beginning to make it invalid.
**Iterations:** 10 000
**Result WITH first-char check:** RUNTIME: 0.026946067810059
**Result WITHOUT first-char check:** RUNTIME: 0.33399415016174
That's quite a difference!

Comment: yes, thanks for the benchmark, I've learned something today :-)

Comment: I'm glad I also could help somehow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be using [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) only.

```
function isJson($string)
{
    return (json_decode($string) !== null);
}
```

But If you insist on checking the first chars, then I would use [substr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).
And I believe your if statement should be using `&&` instead of `||`

```
if ($string[0] != '{' && $string[0] != '['){ .....
```

Or something like this

```
if (!in_array(substr($string, 0, 1), array('{', '[')))
    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

json_encode returns false if the string is not valid Json.

```
function isValidJson($string) {
    if (json_encode($string) === false) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that, but I think it'll be a performance improvement to instantly return false if the first character makes being valid json impossible. Will benchmark later.