# Json Object to PHP array - not converting

Tags: php

I am trying to take a json object stored in a `textarea` and convert it into a php array. I assign the value of the textarea to variable like `$data = $_POST[‘data’]` . When I submit the value of the text I use `json_decode($data, true)` to convert from JSON Object to php array. But nothing happens. It seems like nothing is assigned. How can I achieve the above?

**EDIT: I have added quotes and made the suggestion below and is not working:** [DEMO](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/test/insert_person.php)

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$data = $_POST['data'];
$personArray = json_decode($data, true);
print_r($personArray);
}
```

HTML

```
<textarea name="data">[{
    "firstName": "Jenny",
    "lastName": "LaRusso",
    "phone": "(555) 121-2121",
    "alt_phone": "(555) 123-4567",
    "main1": false,
    "main2": true    
}, {
    "firstName": "Sensei",
    "lastName": "Miyagi",
    "phone": "(555) 444-2222",
    "alt_phone": "(555) 999-1212",
    "main1": true,
    "main2": false
}]</textarea>
```

Comment: Just curious. Did you notice your textarea content before submit?

Comment: HTML looks nice, but have you inspected what `$_POST['data']` contains? That's the data you're dealing with, regardless of where it came from.

Comment: Second that. Try printing out your input before it is parsed. `var_dump($_POST['data'])` should do.

Comment: side note, validation in most cases is very important, here is a great solution for validating the json in the texarea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041741/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-string-is-json-in-php/6041773#6041773

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your PHP code to

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
$data = $_POST['data'];
$data = stripslashes($data); //Stripslashes removes all backslashes :)
$personArray = json_decode($data, true);
print_r($personArray);
}
```

Your JSON object should be this way inside the textarea

```
[{
"firstName": "Jenny",
"lastName": "LaRusso",
"phone": "(555) 121-2121",
"alt_phone": "(555) 123-4567",
"main1": false,
"main2": true    
}, {
"firstName": "Sensei",
"lastName": "Miyagi",
"phone": "(555) 444-2222",
"alt_phone": "(555) 999-1212",
"main1": true,
"main2": false
}]
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: It is not working, check [DEMO](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/test/insert_person.php)

Comment: OOPS, I forgot about the limitations of using "" in your text. I have edited the answer above :)

Answer (score 3):

I think in proper JSON, the keys (like `firstName`) need also be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: I have added the appropriate quotes but it is not working. Check [DEMO](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/test/insert_person.php)

Comment: Are you sure? That JSON is valid now, according to http://jsonlint.com/, so maybe the (next) problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be anything wrong with your PHP code.
For debugging, after setting $personArray, try adding these two lines:

```
var_dump($data);
var_dump($personArray);
```

This should lead to why you are having trouble.

Here you can see what each return type means(if $returnArray is equal to false): http://php.net/json_decode