# Form Request Validation JSON

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm trying to validate that an input is valid json. However it returns success for "123" as input. This does not seem to be valid or at least is not valid in terms of what i need.

Do you know a way to improve the validation for json input?

```
public function rules()
{
    switch($this->method()) {
        case "GET":
            return [];
        case "DELETE":
            return [];
        default:
            return [
                'name' => 'required',
                'templatestring'  => 'required|JSON'
            ];
    }
}
```

Comment: `123` *is* valid JSON as far as PHP's concerned. `json_decode('123')` or try it at http://jsonlint.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`123` is a valid JSON based on the newer [RFC 7159](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc7159.html).

If you're trying to validate a JSON string based on the [RFC 4627](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc4627), you should probably use the `regex` validation rule. For example:

```php
$data = [
    'name'           => 'test',
    'templatestring' => '123'
];

$validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'name'           => 'required',
    'templatestring' => 'required|regex:/[^,:{}\\[\\]0-9.\\-+Eaeflnr-u \\n\\r\\t]/'
]);

// With `123` this returns true (as it fails).
// If you set $data['templatestring'] = '{"test": 123}' this returns false.
return $validator->fails();
```

The regex was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6041857/908174).