# Laravel (Request $request) handling how to check if input is in the correct json format?

Tags: php, json, laravel

So I'm building an api that accepts json input, and catching it in the controller with Request:

```
{
    "val1": "11",
    "val2": "1000",
    "val3": "1001010",
    "val4": "1001"
}
```

However I need to catch a condition when the user didn't use proper json, say like this:

```
{
    "val1": "11",
    "val2": "1000",
    "val3": "1001010"
    "val4": "1001"
}
```

When I return $request on wrong input format, I got empty array. However I have tried using `isset()`, `empty()`, `count()` on request but it still didn't check the parameters.

```
public function foo(Request $request)
{
   if(jsoniswrong($request)){return 'false';}
}
```

I need a way to check the request variable without having to call each values, how do I do this?

edit:
I ended up using this which is simpler. I just realized in Laravel, empty($request) will never return true because even on a bad request it still have objects other than the actual input data. To get the input data, use all(). This solved my problem.

```
    if(empty($request->all())){
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to check if a string is JSON in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041741/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-string-is-json-in-php)

Comment: @thisiskelvin in my case, inside the function, $request is already converted as an object.

Comment: @syam I tried using that but $request is already an object

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. by the way, I can't see the difference between the valid and invalid json you have posted in your question.

Comment: @thisiskelvin the 'invalid' one is missing commas, and in the controller this will be treated as no input. The tricky part is the values are optional since the values are nullable. Now I need to know whether a request is actually empty or in the wrong format.

Comment: Thank you, i've posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may validate an incoming `request` for json using the [validate()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic) method. You can achieve this by doing the following:

```
public function foo(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'json' => 'required|json'
    ]);

    // continue process
}
```

Here, we use the [required](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-required) rule to make sure that the `json` has been passed. We then use the [json](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-json) rule which checks if valid `json` has been passed. A `|` is used to separate validation rules.

If the json is not valid, data about the error will be returned.

**Please note**, you must name the `field/key` of the incoming json data the same as the key within the `validate()` array. e.g. if the `field/key` is called `data` it must be `['data' => 'required|json']`.