# Assign an array to an input value using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

Here is my frontend code:

```
<div>
     <form id="someForm" action="myAPI" method="post">
          <input type="text" name="arr" style="display:none" id="arr">
          <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
     </form>
</div>
```

Here is the array assignment part of my jquery code

```
$(function() {
    var finalArray = {
       "a":1,
       "b":2,
       "c":3
    };

    finalArray = JSON.stringify(finalArray);

    $('#arr').val(finalArray);
}
```

Now, when I handle the submitted finalArray from php backend, it detects the array as a string. **I want to convert it back to array, so that I can parse**.

Having **`[]`** in the input field will not work for me as the finalArray is a **dynamic associative array**.

What am I missing here?

I have already used json_decode, not working for me. It seems like whenever I assign the object in input value, it automatically gets converted as string.

Comment: [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)?

Comment: you can use an ajax call too and send the json string as is (you don't even need to stringify it)

Comment: Note that `finalArray` is not an array, but an object

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP function `json_decode` to parse an array to a JSON array. You could also use a function to check if the array is valid, like in this question: [Fastest way to check if a string is JSON in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041741/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-string-is-json-in-php)

Comment: Could you post the string that you receive in your backend? json_decode should work, so it's you're probably not receiving a valid JSON string when you submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP function json_decode.

```php
$array = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
```